# Huawei Push Kit "All the tokens are invalid"

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After the push function is integrated, the server interface returns error code 80300007 when a push message is sent to some users. I am using a Mate 30  as a test device to obtain a token.

After the server sends a push request, the following response is returned:

```
{"_code": "80300007", "_msg": "All the tokens are invalid", "_requestId": "159496699937460153003301"}
```

In which situations user token will become invalid? This is because the server knows this only when invoking a push request. Can the client determine that if the token is invalid? What should the client do after the token expires?

Answer (score 0):

Error code 80300007 means your token parameters are invalid according to the official guide. Please check your token parameter.
The message receipt capability can be accessed. If invalid tokens are found based on the receipt, push message will not sent to the tokens. For details, please check:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-receipt